# Select all records from one table and check them if they are common in 2nd table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to select all records from a table and join it with another table and check the common records. The problem is that if i use INNER JOIN it only selects the common records and also if where clause is not true it does not select the records from the first table. Here is my sql

```
$stmt=$this->db->prepare("Select * FROM Departamente INNER JOIN Leg_Dep_Cand ON Leg_Dep_Cand.id_d=Departamente.id_d  where Leg_Dep_Cand.id_c=:id_c");   
        $stmt->bindParam(":id_c",$id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $result;
```

Comment: What? Sounds like it's doing exactly what you're asking with the exception of the WHERE? In which case, remove the where part, and the bindParam line?

Comment: i need the where clause because in the second table i have multiple records and i want to fetch only those from the current candidate `id_c`. I guess it can't be done with only one select, i need to make 2 selects,

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * 
FROM Departamente 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Leg_Dep_Cand ON Leg_Dep_Cand.id_d=Departamente.id_d
```

in your results the missing records will then be NULL.